# Multiple APP ID's Under Urban Airship for single device in Android

Tags: android, tags, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I worked with Urban Airship push notifications using Tags. For every new installation UA mantain new 
App ID under audience.In my application I have two options for login: `1.Male 2.Female`

From UA I sended message by adding proper tag.

**Case1:**

- At first installation, under audience my device registered with
  selected tag(I logged as Male) and APP ID.
- In this case everything works good.

**Case2:**

- If I removed the app from device and install again and logged as
  different User(Ex: female).
- Now under audience my device registered with Female Tag and new App
  ID. (Now My device registered with new APP ID under UA)
- If I send push from UA by adding required Female Tag , push received
  to my device.
- But in few cases message from Male tag also  received by device.

**Observation:**

- Now under UA ,my device having two APP ID's with two different tags.
- May be , by that reason my device received both tag messages
  irrespective of selected Tags

**Need solution:**

**Why android maintain new APP ID for every new installation?**

**How to remove previous APP ID of my device from UA before new installation**

(OR)

**How to override Previous APP ID with new APP ID**

**Note:**

I installed application in my device with integrating push notification. Device registered with APID and keeps Active as True.

After re-installation of App, new APID generated and shown Active as True. But, previous APID's status of Active still maintained as True. Why previous APID's Active status not changed to False.

In IOS, after new installation previous Device Token's status changed to inactive. Why happen it in android only??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response from **Urban Airship Support Team**:

Android devices get a new APID whenever you uninstall and reinstall an app, just because of the way GCM works and how our system handles it. Our apologies if this is inconvenient for you, but yes, this is expected behavior. Once you try to push to the old APID, our system will realize that the earlier install is no longer active, and should mark the old APID as inactive. The new one will remain active.

**If you uninstall and reinstall an app fast enough, you may experience behavior like you saw**, where one last push to an old tag for the old APID gets through. The old APID will then be marked inactive by our library if this occurs, and it should not happen again for that installation. We find that this is extremely rare in production and is only ever an issue during testing.

If you want to manually deactivate the old APID that you know is no longer active, just push to it directly and GCM will give us feedback that it is no longer valid. We will no longer attempt to push to it after that point.

Finally, what version of our library are you using? Please make sure you are using the most recent version here: http://urbanairship.com/resources/developer-resources -- older versions did not handle this behavior as reliably.